DHCP Issue with Ubuntu 24.04? Suspect wrong behavior with DHCPNAK
We have the problem that Ubuntu clients cannot obtain an IP address from our DHCP Server (Cisco Router).
As I understand, the problem is that the client does a DHCPREQUEST with its previous IP address even though it receives DHCPNAK from the server.

A Windows client, on the other hand works, because it sends a DHCPREQUEST with 0.0.0.0 after the DCHPNAK and not anymore with his previous IP-Address.
Has anybody encountered the same issue?
I would almost say that the DHCP client in this case does not behave in accordance with RFC.
Source:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131
 *If the client receives a DHCPNAK message, it cannot reuse its
      remembered network address.  It must instead request a new
      address by restarting the configuration process, this time
      using the (non-abbreviated) procedure described in section
      3.1.  This action also corresponds to the client moving to
      the INIT state in the DHCP state diagram.*


can you post your /etc/netplan yaml config file? what is the output of 'ip a'?

Hi Thomas
i should mention that there are about 5 Ubuntu Clients with the same issue. Mine is a fresh install just to see if i can reproduce the issue.
Im not sure which config-file:
-rw-------   1 root root   697 Dec  9 13:26 90-NM-77d80527-f127-4e4f-8630-eba8cb929ed7.yaml
-rw-------   1 root root   368 Dec  9 13:45 50-cloud-init.yaml
-rw-------   1 root root   542 Dec 10 11:29 90-NM-7d6ff642-1608-36ff-a893-73d4eacb01a0.yaml
-rw-------   1 root root   700 Dec 10 15:59 90-NM-4ff07064-f68e-43b9-8721-0ff7ccef8693.yaml

the ip a output is too long but it is for this interface:
5: enx9405bb100939: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 94:05:bb:10:09:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

In /etc/netplan should only be ONE .yaml file usally 01-netcfg.yaml or 50-cloud-init.yaml. if you have more move them to another dir. Here is a simple example of 01-netcfg.yaml. network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
ens32:
dhcp4: yes
dhcp6: yes

Try to put this simple yaml file into /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml. Move any other file in this directory to another location.
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx9405bb100939:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes

Change enx9405bb100939: to the network device you want to use.
Then reboot and see if you got an ip address.

Hi Thomas

i have Identified the .yaml that is associated with my Interface "enx9405bb100939" and deleted it.
i have created the config File you suggested
netplan apply
It works :-) i can change Subnets and the dhcp request works every time.
With my very little Linux knowledge i understand, that it uses "networkd" as a DHCP Client and not "Network Manager" for this specific Interface .
So it must be an Issue with NetworkManager. Do you know where we can report this?
Also thank you so much for your help!
Best Regards
Freshki


You can use both networkd and NetworkManager at the same time, just not on the same interface. networkd is suited for static interfaces, such as connections on servers that don’t change frequently. NetworkManager is designed for desktops and also monitors hardware, for example, detecting and automatically configuring new USB network adapters. If you'd like to know more, feel free to ask another question here.
